# Criar formulário com Components no Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou começando com **Angular 2** e tenho uma dúvida, acredito que simples, na criação de formulários:

Por exemplo em um sistema que contenha os seguintes cadastros:

- Clientes
- Fornecedores
- Transportadoras

Cada cadastro terá seus respectivos campos e também terão campos compartilhados como por exemplo os campos de endereço. Para isso eu poderia criar um **Component** e usá-lo nos respectivos formulários? Como ficaria o envio destes formulários aos objetos da classe usando **Reactive Form**? Isso é o mais correto a se fazer, ou devo em cada formulário recriar os campos de endereço?

Comment: Ainda não utilizei o ReactiveForms, mas geralmente se você possui campos ou uma porção de código que serão replicados constantemente já é um forte indicio que pode ser aplicado a componentização, no seu caso de endereço, acho que se aplica muito bem um component padrão pra tratar endereço.

Comment: Certo, ainda estou um pouco confuso quanto ao envio dos dados do formulário para a classe **TypeScript**, se devo criar vários **forms** a serem enviados pelo evento do click ou um único formulário contendo os **component <app-endereco>** por exemplo.

Comment: Você pode sim criar um <app-endereco> com um @Output retornando um emit para o typescript pai ... de uma olhada no @Output()

Comment: @GabrielBerlanda acho que isso pode te ajudar  [passagem de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269524/componente-pai-receber-dados-de-componente-filho/432013#432013) esse link tem um exemplo onde compartilha dados entre componentes acho que isso pode te ajudar.