# Componente pai receber dados de componente filho

Tags: angular, typescript

É meio confuso o que eu quero mais vamos lá eu tenho meu componente pai que contem alguns botões e um campo de busca, e tenho meu componentes filhos, quero implementar a função do campo de busca no elemento pai, sendo que pra isso preciso receber a lista que foi carregada no elemento filho. Não consegui explicar direito mas vou postar o código para tentar explicar melhor.

elemento pai:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-cadastro',
  template: `
  <div class="container btns-listagem">
    <div class="row campoPesquisa">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 div-btnPesquisa">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="btn-prequisa" type="button"><i _ngcontent-c30="" class="ion-search"></i></button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 btns-funil-novo">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="btn-funil"><i _ngcontent-c30="" class="ion-funnel"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success border-right-0" id="btn-novo"><i _ngcontent-c30="" class="ion-plus-round"></i></button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
})

export class CadastroComponent {}
```

Agora vem a parte complicada.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero receber a lista do elemento filho que foi aberto (nesse caso foi cidade então espero receber a lista das cidades) e então fazer a busca e retornar uma outra lista que será renderizada.
Queria fazer dessa forma, pois tenho varias tela de cadastro não quero ficar repetindo o código html do campo de busca e o código de filtro. 
É possível fazer algo assim, ou tem alguma outra solução mais fácil

Rotas:

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { CadastroComponent } from './cadastro.component';
import { ListaCidadesComponent } from './cidade/cidade.component';
import { ListaSegmentosComponent } from './segmento/segmento.component';
import { ListaSubsegmentosComponent } from './subsegmento/subsegmento.component';
import { ListaUsuariosComponent } from './usuario/usuario.component';
import { ListaVendedoresComponent } from './vendedor/vendedor.component';

const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: CadastroComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'cidade',
            component: ListaCidadesComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'segmento',
            component: ListaSegmentosComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'subsegmento',
            component: ListaSubsegmentosComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'usuario',
            component: ListaUsuariosComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'vendedor',
            component: ListaVendedoresComponent,
        },
    ],
}];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class CadastroRouting { }

export const routedComponents = [
    CadastroComponent,
    ListaCidadesComponent,
    ListaSegmentosComponent,
    ListaSubsegmentosComponent,
    ListaUsuariosComponent,
    ListaVendedoresComponent,
];
```

Exemplo de elemento filho

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { CidadeService } from './cidade.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'ngx-lista-cidades',
    templateUrl: './cidade.component.html',
    providers: [ CidadeService ],
})

export class ListaCidadesComponent implements OnInit {

    private cidades: object[];
    private coluna: string;
    constructor(private cidadeService: CidadeService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.ListaTodasCidades();
    }

    private ListaTodasCidades() {

        this.cidadeService.TodasCidades().then((response: object[]) => {
            this.cidades = response.sort(function(a: any, b: any) {
                return a.NOME < b.NOME ? -1 : a.NOME > b.NOME ? 1 : 0;
            });
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    private ordena(coluna) {

        if (this.coluna === coluna) {
            this.cidades.reverse();
        } else {
            this.cidades.sort((a, b) => {
                return a[coluna] < b[coluna] ? -1 : a[coluna] > b[coluna] ? 1 : 0;
            });
        }
        this.coluna = coluna;
    }
}
```

Estou tentando estender a classe pai para as classes filhas, e funciona em partes, o problema e que elas ficam em escopos diferentes, ou seja na minha view fica uma instancia da classe, e no meu elemento fica outra instancia, elas não se conectam.

Comment: pq vc não usa input e outpus??

Answer (score 1):

No Angular temos algo chamado de @Input e @Output eles permitem trafegar dados entre componentes por exemplo.

**Componente Pai**

```
mandaDados: any;
```

essa variável vai receber os dados exemplo um formulário de filtro.

**Componente Filho**

```
@Input() recebeDados: any;
```

no componente filho crio uma variavel que vai recer os dados lembrando com o **@Input** na frente.

**Quando Chamar o Html Filho**

quando chamar o html filho ou seja seu componet na tag dele você vai ter essa variavel que vai receber um parametro como pode ver na imagem abaixo

```
<seu-component-filho [recebeDados]="mandaDados"></seu-component-filho>
```

sendo assim passando os dados para o outro componente a ideia vale para **@Output**.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia utilizar o @Output para transferir dados do componente filho para o pai ou talvez EventEmitter em um serviço para fazer os dados serem globais.